# Inserting an image to MySql type BLOB from python and show from MySql to PHP

Tags: php, python, base64, python-imaging-library

I am trying to store an image from an url to my database as base64, but when I try to show it in a webpage based on php, it doesn't work..

Here's the python code:

```
import urllib3, io, requests
from PIL import Image
import base64

URL = 'www....com/pic.jpg'
img_conn = urllib3.connection_from_url('www....com/')
img_file = img_conn.urlopen('GET', URL)
image.seek(0)
resized_image = Image.open(image)
resized_image.thumbnail((75,75), Image.ANTIALIAS
resized_image = base64.b64encode(resized_image.tostring())
```

The `resized_image` is added to the database to a column called `pic` type LONGBLOB.

my PHP code looks like something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT pic FROM product LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$decoded_image = base64_decode($row['pic']);

$formImage = imagecreatefromstring($decoded_image);
```

I get the message:

`PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in /home/...`

What am I doing wrong?  Is there another way to save an image from an url inside my database?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if the query actually succeeded and $row is actually base64 data? You're simply ASSUMING nothing could ever go wrong.

Comment: I did debugging and it is base64 data

Comment: then what about `var_dump($decoded_image)`?

Comment: it shows me 30k chars of jibrish

Comment: if it's a jpeg, then somewhere in the first few chars there should be `JFIF`. if icfs() is sayin it's not a recognized format, then it's not a valid jpg. try writing that gibberish out to disk and loading it in some other image editor (heck, even windoze paintbrush) and see if that works. if it doesn't, then your b64 data is bad somehow.

Comment: Ok so I guess there is a problem with the python convertion.
Do you something strange in the code?

Comment: docs say that `tostring()` returns the image in `raw` format. You probably want `save()` instead, which lets you specify output formats.

Comment: Can you be more specific of how the code should be? I'll really appreciate it :)

Comment: no idea. I've never used python.

Comment: Alright thanks Marc I'll check the save function